# Type convertions from C++ data structures into Swift

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, type-conversion

I'm trying to use c++ code from Swift. I need some help with type conversions between the languages. Mostly I would appreciate a code example on converting c++ data structures into Swift understandable form.

For example I have the following method in a c++ file.

```
struct IntPoint {
    cInt X;
    cInt Y;
};

typedef std::vector< IntPoint > Path;

void MinkowskiSum(const Path& pattern, const Path& path, Paths& solution, bool pathIsClosed)
{
    Minkowski(pattern, path, solution, true, pathIsClosed);
    Clipper c;
    c.AddPaths(solution, ptSubject, true);
    c.Execute(ctUnion, solution, pftNonZero, pftNonZero);
}
```

and I have the following in a header-file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void MinkowskiSum(const Path& pattern, const Path& path, Paths& solution, bool pathIsClosed);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and I have a Bridging-Header.h -file for Swift to understand and see the " void MinkowskiSum(const Path& pattern, const Path& path, Paths& solution, bool pathIsClosed);" method.

And Swift and c++ communicate perfectly as long as I use primitive data structures such as int. But I want to use custom structures such as Path (as described above). I would very much appreciate a code example on converting the c++ Path in to Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won’t be able to pass C++ STL containers to Swift easily.  Like it says in the [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html) book:

> You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.

It’s not so bad though.  Swift arrays are a lot like STL vectors for building your input data.

```
struct IntPoint {
    let x: CInt
    let y: CInt
}

var path = [IntPoint(x: 0, y: 0)]
path.append(IntPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
```

Then you can pass that `path` array into a C function:

```
void f(const IntPoint* x);
```

which becomes in Swift:

```
func f(x: UnsafePointer<IntPoint>)

// callable as:
f(path)
```

and

```
void g(IntPoint* x);
```

becomes in Swift:

```
func g(x: UnsafeMutablePointer<IntPoint>)

// callable as:
g(&path)
```

This might not be as nice as passing a vector or Swift array since if you’re passing in an array you have to also pass the element count too, *but* bear in mind that pointers to arrays behave like C++ STL iterators.

So if your `MinkowskiSum` were written in STL algorithm style to take a begin and end iterator to a generic container, you could convert them easily in your C bridge function to turn a pointer plus a count into a begin and end iterator, then call your C++ algorithm with those.

Comment: I built IntPoint and Path into a Swift-file. I'm trying to include that Swift file into a a header-file (see contents above) with #include <MyProject-Swift.h> reference. However Xcode keeps throwing me not found error. Can you guess what I'm missing? I have set up product module name and defines module to YES.